# Convert and Array<string> type to an object where the keys are the strings of the array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type transformation which converts an array of strings into an object where the keys are the values of the strings.

```js
type ObjectFromKeys<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string
}

declare const o: ObjectFromKeys<['foo']>
o.foo // Property 'foo' does not exist on type '[string]'
```

Edit it seems this works:

```js
type ObjectFromKeys<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [K in T as any]: string
}
```

This seems unsafe, is this the right way to do it?

Edit but it does not throw if the value accessed is not in the array

```js
type ObjectFromKeys<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [K in T as any]: string
}

declare const o: ObjectFromKeys<['foo']>
o.bar // This should fail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close to the answer all you have to do is convert an `Array<string>` into a union, which you can do by `T[number]`. see below:

```js
type ObjectFromKeys<T extends Array<string>> = {
  [K in T[number]]: string
}
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEGPVm)